# Is it possible to have a 'vertical' test slice in a Spring Boot environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Hiho,

we are currently developing a service based on Spring Boot. We structure our codebase as mentioned in the Spring Boot reference documentation as a typical layout. This means that we have one package per resource/use case, which contains all classes that are necessary for this resource/use case.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.structuring-your-code.locating-the-main-class

Furthermore we configured the service in a way that no `@Component`s, `@Service`s, `@Repository`s are scanned automatically and that therefore each package needs to provides a `@Configuration` class that defines all necessary beans.

When we start the service, all `@Configuration` classes are interpreted, which leads to the fact that finally all beans of all use cases are available.

In addition, we have implemented a `@SpringBootTest` for each use case. And there happens exactly what happens at runtime of the service: all `@Configuration` classes are interpreted and this leads to the fact that finally all beans of all use cases are available in the application context and therefore in the test.

Now we ask ourselves whether it is possible to configure the respective `@SpringBootTest` in such a way that only the `@Configuration` class is interpreted that is necessary for the specific use case?

We know that this will probably cause the application context to be refreshed multiple times. Nevertheless, we would like to understand if the possibility exists at all.

Any hint can be helpful for us. :)

Comment: If you provide the information in a separated configuration that is certainly possible. However that will have the impact, as you guessed, that for each test that uses a different configuration a new application will be started, which might be (and probably is) inefficient and you are better of with the current solution of 1 application being reused.

Answer (score 0):

The `SpringBootTest` annotation has the parameter `classes` that can be used to pick a specific configuration class:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = YourPackageConigurationClass.class)
```